# Html files parsed as php being parsed differently then *.php files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I added this

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

to my .htaccess, because I need some html-files behave like php-files. Strangly enough, when I load those files "json_decode" and "json_encode" produce a "undefined function"-error. When I use them in a normal php-file everything works fine. It almost seems like an older version of php is being used to parse the html files.

Can someone explain me the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well maybe it was a stupid question. I'm gonna answer it anyway:

`AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html`

is the solution.

**EDIT:** It turned out that my webhosting service had different versions of php installed and thus i needed to be more specific (thanks to the unknown commenter, who deleted his comment, for pointing me in the right direction about the reason behind it.